# How to duplicate training samples with tensorflow dataset API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Suppose the training dataset is `[1,2,3,4,5]` and I'd like to duplicate each sample for a number of times. Let's assume the number is 3 and is the same for all samples, then the result after duplication is: `[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5]`.

But the result that the official `tf.data.Dataset.repeat` function gives is `[1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]`, which does not meet my needs.

How can I implement the duplication and what if the duplication number for each sample is different (for example duplicate each sample[i] for 'weights[i]' times)

Answer (score 2):

Try using `tf.data.Dataset.map`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.range(1, 6)))
repeats = 3
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x: tf.repeat(x, repeats))

for x in dataset:
  print(x)
```

```
tf.Tensor([1 1 1], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2 2 2], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([3 3 3], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([4 4 4], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([5 5 5], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

With a `weights` tensor, try something like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

weights = tf.constant([3, 5, 2, 3, 6])
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.range(1, 6), weights))
dataset = dataset.map(lambda x, y: tf.repeat(x, y))

for x in dataset:
  print(x)
```

```
tf.Tensor([1 1 1], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([2 2 2 2 2], shape=(5,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([3 3], shape=(2,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([4 4 4], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([5 5 5 5 5 5], shape=(6,), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Nice solution. And calling dataset.unbatch() will gives the result I want. Thanks

Comment: What if the dataset is a key-value map, say [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, ... ] and the duplication result I want is [{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 1, 'b': 2}, ...]. `tf.repeat` won't accept dict input

Comment: Ask a new question.. it is free.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5]
a.sort()
print(a)
>[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5,5,5]
```

Comment: That is a quite simple straightforward way. But considering I'm dealing with a larget dataset, it may not be a preferred way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.